# Hidden Id With ComboBox Items?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I know how to add items to a ComboBox, but is there anyway to assign a unique Id to each item? I want to be able to know which Id is associated to each item if it is ever selected.  Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The items in a combobox can be of any object type, and the value that gets displayed is the ToString() value.

So you could create a new class that has a string value for display purposes and a hidden id. Simply override the ToString function to return the display string.

For instance:

```
public class ComboBoxItem
{
   string displayValue;
   string hiddenValue;

   // Constructor
   public ComboBoxItem (string d, string h)
   {
        displayValue = d;
        hiddenValue = h;
   }

   // Accessor
   public string HiddenValue
   {
        get
        {
             return hiddenValue;
        }
   }

   // Override ToString method
   public override string ToString()
   {
        return displayValue;
   }
}
```

And then in your code:

```
// Add item to ComboBox:
ComboBox.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem("DisplayValue", "HiddenValue");

// Get hidden value of selected item:
string hValue = ((ComboBoxItem)ComboBox.SelectedItem).HiddenValue;
```

Comment: Wow that's cool, I did it a little differently, but the idea is the same, thanks a ton!

Comment: Basically, cast is to ComboBoxItem, and then get the hidden value...


     ((ComboBoxItem)ComboBox.SelectedItem).hiddenValue;



Assuming that hiddenValue was public. You'd usually create an accessor for the property instead.

Comment: Added the accessor and comments.

Comment: Thanks @JJ... Man, you saved my time, and unnecessary codings!

Comment: is it possible to set the item based on the hidden value? for example combobox.selecteditem = combobox.hiddenvalue(123)