# error while getting the hiddenValue from the combobox corresponding to the displayed value

Tags: c#, combobox, get, hidden

This is a code I found from this link [Hidden Id With ComboBox Items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762981/hidden-id-with-combobox-items).

```
class ComboBoxItem
{

       string displayValue;
       public string hiddenValue;

       //Constructor
       public ComboBoxItem (string d, string h)
       {
            displayValue = d;
            hiddenValue = h;
       }


       //Accessor
       public string HiddenValue
       {
           get
           {
               return hiddenValue;
           }
       }

       //Override ToString method
       public override string ToString()
       {
            return displayValue;
       }

}
```

Using the below code

```
ComboBox.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem("DisplayValue", "HiddenValue");
```

I was able to display the value that I expected to display. Lets say for example, I saved ComboBox.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem("Mike", "1");. It displays Mike in the combobox without a problem. But now what I need, is to take the corresponding hiddenvalue from the combobox.

For that, I ran the below code.

```
string hValue = ((ComboBoxItem)ComboBox.SelectedItem).HiddenValue;
```

But in the runtime, its throwing me an `NullReferenceException`.  “Object reference not set to an instance of an object.”

Comment: Is an item actually selected when you're attempting this?

Comment: Yes. Its created in the form with values

Comment: But is it actually selected in the ComboBox? Have you physically selected it before running this code?

Comment: Almost all cases of NullReferenceException are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and check what is null. Where is this code being called from?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Thanks sir. It was a dumb mistake! as you said it was not selected.