# Populate combobox from datatable

Tags: c#

I'am struggling with the following, I have a datatable with some columns what i want is to have the items in this column displayed in a combobox. But it must not display double items.

How can i do this?

Comment: Post code, in which you're populating it currently. Most probably you're not checking Page.IsPostBack when you're filling it.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? That it's displaying duplicate items? Please be more specific in your question. What technology are you using? Add more tags.

Comment: Add `Distinct` to your database query

Comment: Sorry being so vague, what i tried was for each loop, but i was way off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void FillComboFromColumnIndex(int columnIndex){
  yourDataTable.AsEnumerable()
               .Select(r=>r[columnIndex])
               .Where(x=>x != null)
               .Distinct().ToList()
               .ForEach(x=>yourComboBox.Items.Add(x));
}
//To add all the items in column at index 1, do this
FillComboFromColumnIndex(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I'm not sure is it right answer on your question because I'm not sure if I have understood you as well:
[Hidden Id With ComboBox Items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762981/hidden-id-with-combobox-items)